# Disable require message when radiobutton is selected to No

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable required message when I checked radio button "No"
However when I submit form nothing happen, it's just redirect to same page and required message is display

**Updated code**

```
//hide/show chapela  Yes/No
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='Chapel']").click(function () {
            var test = $(this).val();
            if (test == 'No') {
                $("div#hideChapel").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("div#hideChapel").show();
             }
        });
    });

    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    });



    $(document).ready(function () {
        var test = $(this).val();
        if(test == 'No'){       
            $("hideChapel").prop("required", false);
        }
        else {
            $("hideChapel").prop("required", true);
        } 
    });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chapel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Chapel, "Yes", new {id="Yes", @class = "styled", htmlAttributes = new { @checked = "true"} })
      Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Chapel, "No", new {id="No", @class = "styled", htmlAttributes = new { @checked = "true" } })
      No
    </label>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Chapel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

**RENDERED HTML**

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<div class="choice" id="uniform-No"><span class="checked"><input checked="checked" class="styled" htmlattributes="{ checked = true }" id="No" name="Chapel" type="radio" value="No" autocomplete="off"></span></div>
                                            No
</label>


<input class="styled" htmlattributes="{ checked = true }" id="Yes" name="Chapel" type="radio" value="Yes" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Please show rendered html instead of the current one :)

Comment: Rendered html. Right click on page and click `Inspect` (`Ctrl + Shift + I`) and copy the html, but not all of it but just this fragment which you showed here.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski check the RENDER HTML part. I added code for radio button. If you need more code let me know

Comment: Ok, I see, what element has `id="hideChapel"`? This line is confusing `$("div#hideChapel").prop('required', false);`. `div` can not have property `required`

Comment: So, what to do know ? How to rechange this part of code ?

Comment: I don't know. to many possibilities. Without clear code it is hard to say.

Comment: The problem is that in my code I have a lot of validation, and this part make me confusing

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski I redesing code . Check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it on form submit, you're currently setting the required attr on document load and on input click. Achieve like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //stop form submitting straight away

    var radio = $('.my-radio');

    if (radio.val() === 'foo') {
        //disable require msg e.g. (this is an example - not a copy + paste)
        $('form input').each(function()
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('required')
        })
    }

    $(this).submit()
})
```

ref:

https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Comment: Thank you  @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs :)

Comment: @Joe123 no probelmo ^.^

Comment: //disable require msg e.g. (this is an example - not a copy + paste) 
Whad did you mean with this part ? :D

Comment: @Joe123 that this is example code, it won't work if you copy + pasted straight into your code (it might if you have your form set up that way - but it's more a demonstration :) )

Comment: Yeah, I get it. 
But know I have problem when I fill the form and Submit button doesn't work

Comment: @Joe123 that may the `$('form').on('submit')` - you can change to `$('.my-input-btn').on('click', function(){` and it should be a-ok :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172889/discussion-between-joe123-and-thisguyhastwothumbs).